# Interchanging FROM and INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, join, select, google-bigquery

I have the following two SQL Queries:

1.

```
"""
SELECT a.id, a.body, a.owner_user_id
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q 
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
ON q.id = a.parent_id
WHERE q.tags LIKE '%bigquery%'
"""
```

2. 

```
"""
SELECT a.id, a.body, a.owner_user_id
FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` as q
ON q.id = a.parent_id
WHERE q.tags LIKE "%bigquery%"
"""
```

I know that the second one is way more expensive. I want to know why this is the case.

My guess - In **1** `post_questions` is retrieved first, and we need to loop over only the question ids, but in **2** we need to loop over the answer parent ids. Since there are way more answers than questions, second one turns out be more expensive.

Am I right? Also, am I right in assuming that the end result of the two queries would be the same?

Comment: SQL is declarative. The `inner join` is actually part of the `from` clause. You're right, they are equivalent. The optimizer should be able to determine the fastest way to execute them regardless.

Comment: Please: Don't edit posts in a way that invalidates reasonable answers. Post a new question. But research it first. You are not the first person to get that error. Also in code questions give a [mre]. I am rolling this back. But the original was an easily found faq. Research before posting & give your research in your post.

Comment: hey @philipxy, No, that doesn't answer my question. it seems like the issue is indentation. I've posted my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62484555/does-indentation-matter-in-sql.

Please recommend on whether I should delete this question or not.

Comment: It does answer it, it has nothing to do with indentation, and there are many other questions asking about the order of inner join arguments, or, what is the same thing in your example, order of tables on either side of an =. If your focus is on implementation speed from the order, that is also a faq & is also answered in the linked answer because it says the order you give doesn't matter.

Comment: In the new question, the order is exactly the same, it's only the indentation of the ON that has changed. But yes this question is answered by the question you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two queries are syntactically equivalent (so they do produce the same results). I don’t know what makes you think that one is more expensive than the other, but it is surely not the case.

SQL is a *descriptive* language, as opposed to a *procedural* language. You tell the database the results you want, and let it decide how to proceed. The query planner parses the query and produces the execution plan it thinks is best. It will happily "start" from one table or the other, regardless of the order in which they appear in the query.

Comment: Thanks GMB. I edited the question. Could you please tell what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

The two should have exactly the same cost in BigQuery.  I am assuming that you are using "on-demand" pricing, because the question would not be appropriate for a flat-rate pricing model.

BigQuery charges on the number of bytes that are read to process the query, not on the complexity of the query.  In fact, multiple references to the same table do not affect the price.  However, the number of columns referenced *does* affect the price.

Both queries are referring to the same tables and columns, so the cost should be the same.

You can review how BigQuery calculates prices in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing).