# Does indentation matter in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm doing a microcourse on Kaggle on which two seemingly identical blocks (except the indentation) produce different results.

**1.**

```
answers_query = """
                SELECT a.id, a.body, a.owner_user_id
                FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q 
                INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
                ON q.id = a.parent_id
                WHERE q.tags LIKE '%bigquery%'
                """
# Set up the query
safe_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(maximum_bytes_billed=10**10)
answers_query_job = client.query(answers_query, job_config = safe_config) # Your code goes here

# API request - run the query, and return a pandas DataFrame
answers_results = answers_query_job.to_dataframe() # Your code goes here

# Preview results
print(answers_results.head())

# Check your answer
q_4.check()
```

Running this code, I get the following error:

> 400 GET https://dp.kaggle.net/bigquery/v2/projects/kaggle-161607/queries/fdc91d96-2162-4e88-895e-7b0e2ffc377e?maxResults=0&location=US: Query exceeded limit for bytes billed: 10000000000. 25131220992 or higher required.

However when I just replace my `answers_query` as follows there is no error:

```
answers_query = """
                SELECT a.id, a.body, a.owner_user_id
                FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions` AS q 
                INNER JOIN `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_answers` AS a
                    ON q.id = a.parent_id
                WHERE q.tags LIKE '%bigquery%'
                """
```

It seems like different indentation is producing different results. I'm extremely new to SQL so I don't know if indentation should matter. From googling and other stack overflow answers it seems indentation is a matter of readability and it shouldn't change things.

Comment: Indentation shouldn't matter.  What happens if you go back to the original now?  I suspect BigQuery may be doing some caching or something from the failed attempt?  Very strange.

Comment: Hey @Frank, thanks for commenting. I restarted the Kernel and tried again, and i got the same results: 1st one raises error, 2nd passes through.

Comment: Right, but what if you run the first, then the second, then the first again?  Or restart, second, and then first?

Comment: Same Result. 1st raises error, 2nd passes, 1st raises error.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from here to ensure if there weren't any typos. Same result. I'm totally confused why this is happening.

Comment: This is a bizarre one.  You might [raise it with Google](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0).  Wouldn't be the first time their stuff had issues.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/learn-forum/100405 ? PS Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also similar kind of problem on Kaggle.com. Kaggle.com online editor interpret syntax in their own way.sometime kaggle interpreter intrpret wrongly. basically kaggle ide primarly targeted to support python. thats why some time indentation matters in kaggle online IDE

Answer (score 0):

Indentation definitely does not matter. As others have implied, the first query will likely be the slower as data is read from disk and cached. Subsequent queries on same data should be faster and will then be within the limit that caused the initial error.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation does not matter as the system reads it regardless of the space.